# error while using Self signed ssl certificate for Mqtt broker

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho, self-signed-certificate

I was using mosquito broker with user name and password authentication. Broker URL is made public so that it can be accessed by a Django web site and raspberry pi
now am trying to implement ssl certificate authentication. but am getting errors like

```
unknown ca, [Win Error 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ,
hand shake failed
```

how to resolve this.

http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/
am following this article to create ssl certificate.
any issue in using self signed certificate in mqtt broker wth public url?

my mosquitto.conf file looks like this

```
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
listener 8883
use_identity_as_username true
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
require_certificate true
```

calling the broker from rasberry pi like this

```
client.tls_set(ca_certs = "certificate path")
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
```

```
import time

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
broker = "broker name"
#mqtt_port = 1883
mqtt_port = 8883

client = mqtt.Client(str(int(time.time())))  # create client object

client.tls_set("./ca.crt")
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
client.connect(broker, mqtt_port)
client.loop_start()
```

Comment: There isn't really enough details in the question to answer this properly, but yes, there are LOTS of problems with using self signed certificates without a detailed understanding about how TLS works. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71617014/edit) the question to show the (Minimal) code that is throwing that error.

Comment: While useful for context, the broker configuration was not what I asked for. I asked for the client code that is giving the error you mentioned. Without seeing how you get up the client we really can't help you.

Comment: How exactly does the first short snippet of code relate to the second?

Comment: thats a test code that i have created for testing  it is also not working.do you know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should remove the following lines from the mosquitto.conf

```
use_identity_as_username true
require_certificate true
```

They are only used when you are using client side certificates which you are not in the code provided.

Second, assuming that the file `ca.crt` is in the same directory as the script and where you are starting the following should work. (It also assumes that the broker certificate has a matching CA/SAN entry to match the broker hostname/IP address)

```
...
client.tls_set_context()
client.tls_set(ca_path="./ca.crt")
client.connect(broker, mqtt_port)
client.loop_start()
```

Another option is this which will disable checking that the broker's certificate is signed by any CA and that it's CA/SAN matches the hostname used to access the broker.

```
...
client.tls_set_context()
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
client.connect(broker, mqtt_port)
client.loop_start()
```

Comment: Thanks @hardlib got the solution created client certificate and now it is working